# How to pulse a sprite using SpriteKit in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am attempting to "pulse" a sprite in SK/SWIFT. My attempts were crude using For-loops and `.setScale`, but they were not working (no errors - just no animation). I feel that using SKActions would perhaps be more elegant.

After using some help from below here is my current implementation. However, it is coming up with compile errors;

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name &
>   Consecutive statement on a line must be separated by a ;

Here is the code I am using:

```
SKAction *pulseUp = [SKAction.scaleTo(3.0, duration: 3.0)]
SKAction *pulseDown = [SKAction.scaleTo(1.0, duration: 3.0)]
SKAction *pulse = [SKAction.sequence(pulseUp, pulseDown)]
SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:pulse]]
[self.playButton runAction: repeat]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is `sprite-kit`? CCSprite and CCSequence etc are cocos2d classes, right?

Comment: I am using Sprite it but yes the above code is Cocos. I want however to find a similar outcome in Sprite it

Comment: You probably should reword the title of your question to make your intention clearer. For a while I was confused by your example code.

Comment: @AnthonyKong thanks Anthony. With your help I have made amendments and feel I am much closer,just as per my question it is still causing errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In xCode Version 8.3.3 with Swift,

```
    let pulseUp = SKAction.scale(to: 3.0, duration: 1.0)
    let pulseDown = SKAction.scale(to: 0.5, duration: 1.0)
    let pulse = SKAction.sequence([pulseUp, pulseDown])
    let repeatPulse = SKAction.repeatForever(pulse)
    self.playButton.run(repeatPulse)
```

Comment: For some reason this is not quite working for me. I get an error claiming "pulseUp" and "pulseDown" are not members of my class.

Comment: @TerranceW - is your declaration of pulseUp and pulseDown made within the scope of your class? If they are not, you cannot reference them as I have done.

Answer (score 1):

It will be similar to something like this:

```
 SKAction *scaleUpAction = [SKAction ...]; // you need to find the CCScaleTo counterpart
 SKAction *scaleDownAction = [SKAction ...];
 SKAction *pulse = [SKAction sequence:@[scaleUpAction, scaleDownAction]];

 [sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:pulse]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a real pulse effect (ie. once scaled up, instantly get to the original scale and repeat forever, do as follows:

```
func addPulseAction(scale: CGFloat = 50, duration: TimeInterval = 0.5) {
    
    let pulse = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.group([
            SKAction.scale(to: scale, duration: duration),
            SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: duration)
        ]),
        SKAction.group([
            SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: 0),
            SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0)
        ])
    ])
    let shockwave = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 1)
    node.addChild(shockwave)
    
    shockwave.run(SKAction.repeatForever(pulse))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As extension :

```
    import SpriteKit


    extension SKSpriteNode {

    

    private static let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.455, blue: 0.756, alpha: 0.45)

    

    func addPulseEffect(circleOfRadius: CGFloat, backgroundColor: UIColor = fillColor) {

        

        let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: circleOfRadius)

        circle.fillColor = backgroundColor

        circle.lineWidth = 0.0

        circle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        self.addChild(circle)

        let scale = SKAction.scale(to: 3.0, duration: 1.0)

        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)

        let pulseGroup = SKAction.sequence([scale, fadeOut])

        let repeatSequence = SKAction.repeatForever(pulseGroup)

        circle.run(repeatSequence)

        

    }

    

    func repeatPulseEffectForEver(circleOfRadius: CGFloat) {

        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.8, repeats: true) { (timer) in

            self.addPulseEffect(circleOfRadius: circleOfRadius)

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: No need to install a timer. Simply add a new scale to your group as follows, and take rid for your 'repeatPulseEffectForEver()': let pulseGroup = SKAction.sequence([scale, fadeOut, SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration0)])